# Grails springSecurityService.currentUser returns null

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-platform-core

I have this service class:

```
class UserService {

    def springSecurityService

    @Listener(topic = 'currentUser', namespace = 'auth')
    public User getCurrentUser(){
        return springSecurityService.currentUser
    }

    def authenticate(OAuthToken oAuthToken){
        SecurityContextHolder.context.authentication = oAuthToken
        return springSecurityService.currentUser
    }
}
```

If I use the authenticate method, `springSecurityService.currentUser` returns the current user. But if I am already logged in I want to get a current user with `getCurrentUser` method and it returns null. I debugged the `Springsecurityservice.getCurrentUser` method and the method "isLoggedIn" returns false.

But if I try this in my view it works:

```
<sec:ifLoggedIn>Yeeees</sec:ifLoggedIn>
```

**UPDATE:**

When I run `UserService.getCurrentUser` the SCH.context.authentication in SecurityService returns null. After that call, the view is being rendered and `SCH.context.authentication` returns a right authentication.

**UPDATE 2:**

I analysed it and it seems to happen only if I use it with event bus. If I call getCurrentUser directly from controller, it works fine, but if I use event bus it doesn't.
I use Event Bus from platform-core plugin. Is there another SCH.context for Event Bus?

Comment: But what is the reason to get current user using event?

Comment: I just want to decouple my controller/services.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution. The problem was that Event Bus works within a thread and spring context will not be delivered to threads by default.

The option 'context holder strategy' in config solve this:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.sch.strategyName = org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL
```

http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/latest/#miscProperties

Answer (score 0):

You can get the principal and then search the user, in mycase the domain is AppUser

```
        def user = springSecurityService.getPrincipal()
        def testUser =AppUser.findByUsername(user.username)
```